# Why sizeof() operator isn't giving the correct size?

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures

I am trying to implement insertion of an element in an array on my computer but `size_array=sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` was giving the wrong answer, the array contains 5 elements but this piece of code was printing size equal to 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insert(int * array,int number_of_elements,int index,int value)
{
    int size_array,i;

    size_array=sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    printf("%d\n",size_array);

    if(size_array==number_of_elements)
    {
        printf("Insertion failed");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=number_of_elements;i>index;i--)
        {
           array[i]=array[i-1];
        }
        array[index]=value;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[5],i,number_of_elements=5,value=-9,index=3;

    for(i=0;i<=number_of_elements-1;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<=number_of_elements-1;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    insert(array,number_of_elements,index,value);

    for(i=0;i<=number_of_elements;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the location where you use it, `sizeof(array)` is the size of `int *`

Comment: Because pointer isn't an array

Comment: `sizeof(array)` is the size of the pointer, not the size of the array.

Comment: @qrdl What should I do to correct it?

Comment: @ShreyanshPathak you need to pass array size as function param

Comment: Side note: Instead of writing `for(i=0;i<=number_of_elements-1;i++)`, it is easier and more common to write `for(i=0;i<number_of_elements;i++)`.

Comment: @qrdl So it means I can't find the size of an array using pointer to it?

Comment: You are already passing the number of elements in the array to the function, in the `number_of_elements` argument. Why are you attempting to calculate the number of elements again using  `size_array=sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);`?

Comment: @ShreyanshPathak: No, there is no way to obtain the size of an array from a pointer to the start of the array. You must keep track of that information by some other means.

Comment: This loop will cause you to access `array` out of bounds: `for(i=0;i<=number_of_elements;i++)`. Note that in C, arrays are fixed size and cannot be increased at runtime.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I was calculating `size_array` because, if number_of_elements and size_array come out to be equal then I shouldn't be able to insert an element in the array, please guide me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Is `number_of_elements` supposed to represent the number of valid elements inside the array, or the maximum size of the array?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel `number_of_elements` represent the number of elements which I want to insert in the array using scanf , it is not the maximum size of the array .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237547/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-shreyansh-pathak).

Comment: A pointer points to a *single* object - that object *may* be the first element of an array, but there’s no way to know that based on the pointer value alone.  You will have to keep track of the array size and pass that size as a separate parameter to the function.